# Lightning Combo box overflowing outside table column

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-combobox

I have added a combobox in lwc using table structure and it is overflowing to the next column. Below is the code I used.

```
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
            <thead  class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <tr>
                <th  scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">Asset Type</div>
                    <div> <template if:true={assetTypeValues.data}>
                        <lightning-combobox name="progress"  placeholder="Choose on"
                            options={assetTypeValues.data.values} onchange={handleChange}>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                    </template></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
 </table>
```

[image: output image]

Can anyone help?
Note: I need to display 15 columns using table structure and hence went with html table.

After applying the css the values are truncated as below
[image: after applying css]

Answer (score 1):

The `lightning-combobox` component uses the class `.slds-dropdown_fluid` to set the dropdown width using the variable `--lwc-sizeXSmall` which has a default value of **12rem**.

Custom CSS can be used to overwrite this value as required.

```html
<lightning-combobox
  class="combobox-custom-width"
  name="progress"
  placeholder="Select"
  options={options}
>
</lightning-combobox>
```

```css
.combobox-custom-width{
    --lwc-sizeXSmall: 8rem;
}
```

Comment: I applied the CSS and it is now showing the picklist values as truncated. Attached screenshot above.

Comment: Yes it is due to limited space. You can view the full text by hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

<lightning-combobox
class="combobox-custom-width"
name="progress"
placeholder="Select"
options={options} style="width:320px;"

> 

Please check it its working.